# For a stopping time $T$ adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$, is $\mathbb{1}[T=t]\in\mathcal{F}_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

For a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{T}}$, the random variable $T$ is a stopping time if $\mathbb{1}[T\leq t]\in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t$. The textbook I'm reading emphasizes that in the discrete case $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{N}$, this is equivalent to $\mathbb{1}[T=n]\in \mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n$. I believe that in the continuous case it is still true that $\mathbb{1}[T=t]\in\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t$; it is just the converse that does not hold.

Indeed, for each $t$ the constant time $t$ is trivially a stopping time, and we have the general result that $\mathbb{1}[T=S]\in \mathcal{F}_{T\wedge S}$ for $T,S$ stopping times. Taking $S=t$ gives $\mathbb{1}[T=t]\in\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge t}\subseteq\mathcal{F}_{t}$ for all $t$. Is anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking if $T$ is a $\mathcal F_t$-stopping time implies that $\mathsf 1_{\{T=t\}}\in\mathcal F_t$? If so, I believe the answer is yes, but remember that if $T$ is a continuous random variable then $\mathbb P(T=t)=0$, so this is somewhat of a moot point.

Comment: That is what I am asking. But $T$'s distribution might have an atomic component, no?